# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.3.5 duplicate code not highlighted

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, code-duplication

IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.3.5 duplicate code not highlighted on the fly.
I've checked the checkbox from `Settings -> Inspections -> General` but nothing is highlighted when I have duplicated code in Java.

```
  public void testSt() {
        List<String> ss = new ArrayList<>();
        ss.add("43");
        ss.add("43");
        ss.add("43");

    }

  public void testSt2() {
        List<String> ss = new ArrayList<>();
        ss.add("43");
        ss.add("43");
        ss.add("43");
   }
```

Can someone help?

Comment: I think by default intellij provide this feature .

Comment: Eitherway for me is not working, don't know why.

Comment: This is an ultimate edition only feature. Check that your license is currently active in Help > About.

Comment: Done that already, yes it is an active licence.Thanks for replying.Some files of intellij are been corupted I guess, I tried also deleting the system and config folders from intellij but no luck.

Comment: Just upgraded from 2018.3.4 to 2018.3.5 after seeing your post. Inspection works as before - I did few tests before and after upgrade. Maybe try to invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: Something is broke on intellij on my machine, I tried also reinstalling intellij but still no luck.Thanks anyway for your replays

Comment: Can you add an example of the code that should be marked duplicate? Both sides please.

Comment: Hi @KarolDowbecki, I posted the code in the question. If I right click on the class and choose Analyze->locate duplicates it founds it.

Comment: I discovered that the duplicate code detection on the fly works on all my source code but not on my tests, where the problem started. So I got some progress, now I need to figure it out why is not working same on the test folders.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the issue on my problem, I'll leave it here, in case others will need it.
From version 2018 of IntelliJ Ultimate you need to have at least some units of code duplicated in order to be detected on the fly.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-duplication-analysis-settings.html

If you have just 2-3 lines of duplicate code it will not be detected.

You can play with the settings on "Do not show duplicates simpler than"
[image]

Hope others will benefit from my experience.
Thank you.